# How to write 3 Million rows to an Excel File Using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, export-to-excel, sxssf

I have more than 2 Million rows for a search criteria in my db which i have to Export into a xlsx file. I am using apache POI SXSSF to achieve that.

I am getting the data chunk by chunk from DB with 130+ columns and writing it into WorkSheet by creating multiple sheets, each sheet has 400K rows. But i am facing the issue when it reaches 1.1M data, my code is not responding after that also it is not throwing any error as well.

I have 2 confusions based on this issue.

1. Can we handle more than 1 M data on a  single WorkBook.
2. Can Excel handle more than 1M records on multiple sheets.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is yes. I had `*.xlsx` workbooks in GB size already (of course not created by `apache poi`)  and while one sheet can only have 2^20 = 1,048,576 rows, multiple sheets having up to 1,048,576 rows each are possible in one workbook. Your problem clearly comes from too low usable RAM memory while executing. But on the other side: More than 2 million data rows in one Excel workbook sounds useless to me. Who shall be able working with those huge amount of data in Excel?

Comment: But Axel SXSSF shouldn't create RAM issue since i am not keeping more data on heap memory. The idea of having that amount of data is for using it as a dump file for another system.

Comment: If you have a way to handle huge data effectively, i mean solutions other than SXSSF then please provide.

Comment: If `SXSSF` is used correctly it should not having heap space issues, right. But is it used correctly? And it creates temporary files, so it also could have issues in file system usage. And using Excel files as dump files is a bad idea in my opinion. Do using `XML` files for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be disastrous to write 2 million rows in an excel sheet. If you have a requirement to write to some file then choose to write in CSV files as it's much lighter than excel. 
And about the max number of rows allowed--~65k in 2003, 1,048,576 in 2007+
 you can also use API 
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL97.getMaxRows() and 
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007.getMaxRows()

Comment: The question was not about having 2 million rows in one **sheet** but in **multiple** sheets in one **workbook**.  And no, `CSV` is not the answer for serializing such an amount of data records since `CSV` is **very** bad structured text format. `XML` is the better answer.

Comment: Uzair i can understand opening an Excel file with more than 1M data is a nightmare, most of the time it doesn't work. But i just need to know why my code was stuck though i was writing only 400K on a sheet.

Comment: Dear Axel writing this enormous data to XML could never be better than CSV. XMLs are much heavier than CSV and would take substantial time and memory to parse XML doc. XML and excel never meant to be used to write this much data.

Comment: Dear @user3247425
I really don't know the exact reason . Your code stop responding after reaching a certain threshold may be because of your file stop responding, it's depends on your system configuration . You should monitor  system health while writing to a file and wait for some time , most probably it would take time to write and respond.